# Core Data relationship is complicated

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data, swiftui, relationship

I tried the great tutorial from Paul Hudson to have a look at the Core Data relationship: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/one-to-many-relationships-with-core-data-swiftui-and-fetchrequest and everything worked like a charm.

But unfortunately this isn't what I really need and when I make some changes it's not working like I'd love to!

Here's what I'm trying to make:

```
VStack {
    ForEach(countries) { country in
        HStack {
            Text(country.wrappedFullName)
            Spacer()
            Button("Add") {

                // I'd love to add a candy from here
                // And based on the "id" and not the "shortName"

                let candy = Candy(context: moc)
                candy.id = UUID()
                candy.date = Date()
                candy.name = "Example"

                candy.origin = Country(context: moc) // I have to repeat that?
                candy.origin?.id = UUID() // This isn't right!

                try? moc.save()

            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then, in another screen (SwiftUI View), I list every candies from the selected country.

So what am I doing wrong? Do you know a simple solution to this problem? Thanks in advance. ✌️

Comment: What is `countries`, can't you do `candy.origin = country` without creating a new country object?

Comment: Thanks a lot @JoakimDanielson! This is what I was looking for actually. I don't know why I overcomplicated everything. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to have a `Country` object to assign as the origin of the `Candy`.

Here are the steps:

```
// Create the Candy
let candy = Candy(context: moc)
candy.id = UUID()
candy.date = Date()
candy.name = "Example"

// Create the Country
let country = Country(context: moc)
country.id = UUID()
country.name = "Swiftland"

// Link both
candy.origin = country

try? moc.save()
```

(Edit)
*Note: the code above is just to exemplify the creation of a relationship between two Core Data objects. It should not be used "as-is" inside the* `Button` *in the question, as it would create new candies and countries at every hit. Place each part of the code above where appropriate to avoid duplicates.*

Comment: Thanks @HunterLion. I just needed `candy.origin = country`. Thanks again!

Comment: @Alexnnd Why are you marking this answer as accepted? It is clearly wrong since it creates a new country each time you save a Candy object. Don't accept answers just for fun or because you think you have to, other people might read your question and this answer looking for a solution to a similar problem and incorrectly believing this is it.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Because there was the line I needed inside this block of code even if the "Create the Country" wasn't really relevant. It wasn't for fun.

Comment: Ok, I now "fun" wasn't a good choice of words but I couldn't think of anything better  right then. That said, you can't just pick one line because it is the whole answer that matter and anyone else can't know that is what you accepted it for. Remember that this answer is not only for you but for others as well with a similar issue so you might fool others into thinking this is how it should be done.